# Send data object using key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create something like quick switch to send Java object based on Key. I tried this:

```
private MessageProcessor defaultProcessor;
private Map<String, MessageProcessor> processors;

MessageProcessor messageProcessor = processors.getOrDefault(payloadObject.getName(), defaultProcessor);
public ResponseObject process(@RequestBody PayloadObject payloadObject)
{
   MessageProcessor messageProcessor = processors.getOrDefault(payloadObject.getName(), defaultProcessor);
   return messageProcessor.processMessage(payloadObject);
}


public interface MessageProcessor {

    ResponseObject processMessage(PayloadObject payloadObject);
}

// if we send a key first send to this class the payload

@Component("first")
public class FirstService implements MessageProcessor {

    @Override
    public ResponseObject processMessage(PayloadObject payloadObject) {
        return new ResponseObject("first payload");
    }
}
```

Full code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Code_Switch_Select_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/poc/PocController.java

Is it possible to use `@Service("first")` instead of `@Component("first")` and also how I can make the code much more simple?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*Is it possible to use `@Service("first")` instead of `@Component("first")`"* - Counter-questions: why do you want a `@Service`? - Have you taken a look at [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)?--- "* how I can make the code much more simple?*" - If the code works as expected, it might be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your source code, it can be simplified by using `Class` itself.

Here is an example of some Spring HTTP Converters for `Resource` class: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L74

The idea is that Spring can easily create a POJO for you from JSON/XML/etc and in runtime you can get its class `myvar.getClass()` to determine what [OOP Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to choose.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation from Spring is to use @Service stereotype for Service classes. @Service has additional behaviour such as Aspect support.

Spring documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations